# Rstudio has been throwing errors since my attempt to install the devtools package

Tags: r, package, devtools

I did not manage to download devtools as it said I did not have enough space. I then deleted the packages MASS and anitrust as I thought I could free up some space. I have not been able load/download any packages successfully since then. The errors are as follows:

```
>Error:  package ‘rlang’ does not have a namespace
> library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
 package ‘rlang’ does not have a namespace
> install.packages("rlang")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

>https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘U:/My Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/rlang_0.4.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1122196 bytes (1.1 MB)
downloaded 1.1 MB

>Error in install.packages : cannot open file 'U:/My Documents/R/win-library/3.6/file33d876f8f4d/rlang/DESCRIPTION': Not enough space
> library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
 package ‘rlang’ does not have a namespace 

>https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘U:/My Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘Rtools’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)
```

I am also using university computers but I have never had these issues before.

Comment: Sorry, but *"not enough space"* is not something we can really help with. Also, while using a network drive for your libpath is supported, there are occasionally problems with it. Further, it is not clear if you have installed Rtools.

Comment: @r2evans , thank you for editing the question and your response. I was not able to download Rtools.

Comment: `Rtools` is not a package, it's a set of tools needed to compile R and several packages from source, it includes unix/linux tools not available in Windows.

Comment: There is no magic way to use Rtools without downloading and installing it. If you are so tight on space, then the additional 792MB that Rtools requires will not be easy. (For comparison, R by itself is between 202MB (R-3.5) and 282MB (R-3.6), and RStudio -- technically not required to use R -- is 780MB.)